# How to validate date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a textbox which allows users to choose a date from a calendar in `mm/dd/yyyy` format. I used the `pikaday` and `moment` libraries to achieve this. Now, if the user selects a date that is not in the future, I want to show an error in a label saying that the date is invalid. What is the 'best' way to achieve this? Working with dates in Javascript turned out to be quite a headache.I have provided my current approach:

`textbox:`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDepartureDate" runat="server" ForeColor="Gray" onfocus="txtOnFocusDeparture(this)" onblur="txtOnBlurDeparture(this)" oninput="oninputDeparture()" AutoPostBack="True">DEPARTURE DATE</asp:TextBox>
```

`script:`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function oninputDeparture() {
                        var inputDate = moment(document.getElementById('txtDepartureDate').value, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
                        var todayDate = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
                        var lblError = document.getElementById('lblError');
                        var daysDiff = todayDate.diff(inputDate, 'days');
                        if (daysDiff <= 0) {
                            lblError.innerText = "Departure Day should be after today";
                        }
                        else {
                            lblError.innerText = "";
                        }

                    }

                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var todayDate = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
var lblError = document.getElementById('lblError');
var daysDiff = todayDate.diff(inputDate, 'days');
```

[moment.diff](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/) requires a moment object. `todayDate` is assigned as string in this case.

Also consider quick exit when the user is still typing

Have a look at the example.

```js
var dateInput = document.getElementById('txtDepartureDate');
var lblError = document.getElementById('lblError');

function setError(text) {
  lblError.innerText = text
}


function oninputDeparture() {
  var value = dateInput.value;
  var dateValue = moment(value, 'DD/MM/YYYY');

  if (value.length < 10 || !dateValue.isValid()) {
    return;
  }

  var todayDate = moment();

  var daysDiff = todayDate.diff(dateValue, 'days');

  if (daysDiff >= 0 && !dateValue.isAfter(todayDate, 'days')) {
  
    setError("Departure Day should be after today");
  } else {
    setError("");
  }

}

setTimeout(() => {
  dateInput.value = moment().add(1, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
  oninputDeparture()
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtDepartureDate" type="text" oninput="oninputDeparture()" />
<div id="lblError"></div>
```